# How to manipulate multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have the following table:

```
  X Y
A 4 8
B 2 6
C 5 4
D 6 3
E 9 13
```

But I would like to re-arrange this to look like:

```
AX AY BX BY CX CY......
4  8  2  6  5  4
```

I am working in **R** and get the table by doing

```
table(db[,1],db[,2])
```

How can I change the command to get the desired output?

Comment: Include your data using `dput` to make this easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is set up this way:

```
db <- data.frame(
  c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 2), rep("C", 5), rep("D", 6), rep("E", 9), 
    rep("A", 8), rep("B", 6), rep("C", 4), rep("D", 3), rep("E", 13)),
  c(rep("X", 26), rep("Y", 34)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

tab <- table(db[,1],db[,2])
```

You could do this in a one-liner:

```
array(tab, dimnames = list(do.call("paste0", expand.grid(dimnames(tab)))))
AX BX CX DX EX AY BY CY DY EY 
 4  2  5  6  9  8  6  4  3 13
```

Answer (score 5):

If you do not care about the names and you have numeric data then the easiest solution would be to coerce to a matrix and then to a vector like so:

```
as.vector( t( x ) )
# [1]  4  8  2  6  5  4  6  3  9 13
```

If you also want to preserve the names, use `expand.grid` to get the combinations...

```
#  The data
y <-  as.vector( t( x ) )

#  Combinations of row and column names
nms <- expand.grid( colnames(x) , rownames(x)  )  

# Rename vector with desired names
names(y) <- paste0( nms[,2] , nms[,1] )

#AX AY BX BY CX CY DX DY EX EY 
# 4  8  2  6  5  4  6  3  9 13
```

Comment: ...or maybe just `unlist` it, although the order would be different.

Comment: If your original data is `df` and final vector is `x`,`names(x) = do.call("c",lapply(colnames(df),function(x){paste0(rownames(df),x)}))`

Comment: @joran I was trying to preserve the order - I didn't know if that was important. Now also with names!